# Unescape JSON string

Tags: json, gson

I have a .NET service that reports back escaped JSON string

```
[
"{\"uid\":3298534883331,\"id\":\"foo\",\"name\":\"Foo Bar\",\"address\":{\"uid\":3298534883332,\"city\":\"Shanghai\",\"street\":\"Ke Yuan Street\"}}",
"{\"uid\":3298534883333,\"id\":\"foo\",\"name\":\"Foo Bar\",\"address\":{\"uid\":3298534883334,\"city\":\"Shanghai\",\"street\":\"Ke Yuan Street\"}}"
]
```

From Java side I am using GSON, and it wants to have unescaped JSON

```
[
{"uid":0,"id":"foo","name":"Foo Bar","address":{"uid":0,"city":"Shanghai","street":"Ke Yuan Street"}},
{"uid":0,"id":"foo","name":"Foo Bar","address":{"uid":0,"city":"Shanghai","street":"Ke Yuan Street"}}
]
```

Is there any standard procedure to unescape JSON string?

Here is .NET part

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(
        UriTemplate = "{Database}/{ContainerName}?query={tag}",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string[] Get(string database, string containerName, string tag);
```

Inside it uses JSON.net

Java client

```
    String json = webResource.
        queryParam("query", "id = 'foo' AND name = 'Foo Bar'").
        get(String.class);
```

From Eclipse debugger I can see differences in two strings, what GSON generates and what comes back
You can note an extra " for each object at the start and the end

Comment: How are you showing the string? Is it *really* escaped, or is that just something you're getting from the debugger? How are you returning the string from your .NET app?

Comment: Updated post with mode details

Answer (score -1):

It seems that your server is actually returning a string array:

```
string[] Get(string database, string containerName, string tag);
```

and that's exactly what the client is getting:

```
[
    "string 1",
    "string 2",
    ...
    "string N"
]
```

You should return an array of objects:

```
MyClass[] Get(string database, string containerName, string tag);
```

and you'll then get something like:

```
[
    {"MyProperty1": "value1_1", ..., "MyPropertyM": "value1_M"},
    {"MyProperty1": "value2_1", ..., "MyPropertyM": "value2_M"},
    ...
    {"MyProperty1": "valueN_1", ..., "MyPropertyM": "valueN_M"},
]
```

Being MyClass defined like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    public string MyProperty1 { get; set; }
    public string MyProperty2 { get; set; }
    ...
    public string MyPropertyM { get; set; }
}
```